# Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy does not support the "cros-origin" policy

Tags: node.js, cors

```js
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({policy:"cros-origin"}));
```

for this line of code the error is

```js
throw new Error(`Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy does not support the ${JSON. string(policy)} policy`)
```

```
Error: Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy does not support the "cros-origin" policy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `cros-origin` instead of `cross-origin`. This should work:

`app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));`